# Scaffold-DbContext - CultureNotFoundException: Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. par'name' en-us is an invalid

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
Scaffold-DbContext "connection string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities
```

I am running the command above and I get the following error, tried both with .NET 7 and 8 preview.

I even added `<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>` to project but that didn't do anything.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

> System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Only the invariant
> culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. See
> https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode for more information.
> (Parameter 'name') en-us is an invalid culture identifier.    at
> System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas,
> IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1
> schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) Only the invariant culture is supported in
> globalization-invariant mode. See
> https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode for more information.
> (Parameter 'name') en-us is an invalid culture identifier.

Comment: You should try actually setting `InvariantGlobalization` to **false**, since the error message indicates that it is somehow active (*true*) for the startup project. In case this is not the startup project, and the startup project is AspNet.Core app which needs that mode, I guess you have to create fake console project and use it for executing EF Core design time commands.  In general the error is from SqlServer provider, see https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/220

Answer (score 56):

You have to make changes in `.csproj` file of your project,  need to add `InvariantGlobalization` attribute to `false` in `PropertyGroup`.

This is how it looks.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: For more context on this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52319. It seems that the Visual Studio template for new WebAPI projects now includes this setting by default and sets it to "true". You can safely remove this setting, or set it to "false". It wasn't intended to be included in this project type.

Answer (score -3):

Check your .csproj file; ensure the following line is added within the `<PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup>` section:
`<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>`

If it is not available, add the line to fix the issue. If available, ensure it is set to false.

Example .csproj entry:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: How does this answer improve on the existing answers?