# ef scaffold with named connection fails invariant culture identifier

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to setup a new .net project with Entity Framework and a scaffolded model from my database.
So I ran:

```
dotnet new webapi
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet user-secrets init
dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings.Database "My Connection String"
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings.Database Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

The scaffold command failed with the message:

```
Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. See https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode for more information. (Parameter 'name')
en-us is an invalid culture identifier.
```

I already found this: [Scaffold-DbContext - CultureNotFoundException: Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. par'name' en-us is an invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76394279/scaffold-dbcontext-culturenotfoundexception-only-the-invariant-culture-is-sup) but changing the `<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>` did not have any effect.

I tried to change the .NET version to 6, 7 and 8. I am running on windows, since I found this issue happening on docker.

Interestingly it works with the scaffold command with the connection string.

Comment: does your app have `appsettings.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my `dotnet-ef` by `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`. Now it is working fine. So there seemed to a version mismatch.